# `have` matcher accepts items in singular form?

Tags: ruby, rspec

I'm doing tutorial for Rspec in Code school and there is a sample code like this.

```
describe Zombie do
  it 'increases the number of tweets' do
    zombie = Zombie.new(name: 'Ash')
    zombie.tweets.new(message: "Arrrgggggggghhhhh")
    zombie.tweets.should have(1).tweets
  end
end
```

It expects that there is a tweet, so I've rewrite `have(1).tweets` to `have(1).tweet`. Then it works also.

But in [documentation](https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-12/docs/built-in-matchers/have-n-items-matcher) there is no indication that singular form is accepted.

I want to know which way is recommended to use, `have(1).tweets` or `have(1).tweet`.

Comment: I think the plural form is the recommended since the singular form is not mentioned in the doc

Comment: `have(1).tweets` feels unnatural. Since Rspec is trying to make tests as readable as possible, I would personally use singular form here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The method call after `have(n)` is "syntactic sugar" and can be anything you want, as described in the Relish documentation at https://www.relishapp.com/rspec/rspec-expectations/v/2-99/docs/built-in-matchers/have-n-items-matcher as well as earlier versions.

I referenced the 2.99 Relish page because as of 3.0, this functionality has been moved to a separate `rspec-collections_matcher` gem at https://github.com/rspec/rspec-collection_matchers  You won't find that have matchers mentioned in the 3.0 documentation.

As for whether the singular or plural form of "tweet" should be used, I believe there is a consensus that in terms of the English language, the singular form represents the correct grammar for this specific case. See https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/165244/is-negative-one-plural for a case for which there is no clear consensus.